# Run octave faster

Tags: memory, octave

I am very new to GNU Octave, but need to run a script, `foo.m` that was written in octave. In java, I know it's possible to allocate more memory to a process, and thereby speed it up, using, e.g., `-Xmx4g`. Is there a similar option in octave?

Comment: Maybe your function itself can be optimized to run faster? Can you post it?

Comment: It's a very involved, multi-script process. Way way outside of my purview. I'm just throwing a variable at it, and running it.

Comment: I've personally had experiences where Matlab runs the script ~2x faster than octave, and they are **nearly** compatible. Maybe it runs fine, maybe you'd have to tweak it a little, though if you start tweaking it, you might as well tweak it enough to run it with julia.

Comment: You could also try octave's JIT compiler --mentioned in 19.5 of [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/octave.pdf)--which looks like you'd only need to add lines around blocks instead of changing any lines of the script itself, though I'm not sure (never used it personally), and the docs mention it's experimental

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In java, I know it's possible to allocate more memory to a process, and thereby speed it up, using, e.g., -Xmx4g. Is there a similar option in octave?

The answer for your question is **no**.

The only flag you can specify during startup of the Octave interpreter that may improve performance is `--jit-compiler`. For more info, read `octave --help`.

The jit compiler was a GSoC project in 2012 and was a proof of concept with fairly limited capabilities. Since it didn't really do much, it has been removed in Octave 7.

**Modern Octave has no JIT compiler**.

Comment: For those interested in JIT compilation, the Julia language is the way to go: https://julialang.org